# ED endings: identifying Adjectives or Verb Past Participles

Tags: adjectives, past-participles

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this. In the passive voice, we could see sentences like these:

***"The car is heated."***

"His spirits are lifted."

"The books are packed." vs "The concert hall is packed."

"The wall is painted."

When such sentences are not in the past, I can't figure out how to identify if the final word is an adjective, a past participle or a verb.

In sentences using the perfect tenses, I understand that we use the past participle, but is this acting as an adjective or as a verb? Eg:

***"He had been broken by the news."***

*"They've been bored since Friday." (This I'm pretty sure is the adjective, but I'm putting it in here for completeness)*

I've read in some places that we should just call it a past participle and leave it at that, but this is more confusing to me. How can it be a past participle and not act as either an adjective or a verb? Surely it must be a participle acting as a verb or an adjective?

And in a sentence like: ***"The speaker wants to be transferred,"*** am I right that this final word is an adjective because it is following "to be"?

I suppose this post is just illustrating my numerous questions about this. As you can see, I have many. If there are any resources out there that someone could refer me to, or if someone could offer a detailed explanation about this usage, I would be most grateful.

MA

Answer (score 2):

Many of the examples could be interpreted as either a verb or an adjective.

> "The wall is painted."

- If you point to a wall covered in paints, then "painted" is an adjective.
- If you are narrating a story, and there's a live scene of painters actively painting the wall, then "is painted" could be a passive verb construction.

> "The car is heated."

- If you are narrating a story, and there's a scene of a blow torch which is blasting the car, then "is heated" could be a passive verb construction.
- If you are referring to an already warm car that has temperature controls, then "heated" could be an adjective.

> The speaker wants to be transferred

This seems very much like a passive verb, rather than an adjective.

> Am I right that this final word is an adjective because it is following "to be"?

Do you have a link or a reference for this "rule" that it must be an adjective?  I don't believe so.

> The wall is going *to be* painted.

This seems to contain the dual meanings of "painted", mentioned earlier.

1. A passive verb, as in "The wall is going to be destroyed."

or

2. An adjective, as in "After they paint it, the wall is going to be blue."

---

If the same exact sentence can have two meanings, which is the right one?

Often times, based on the context, one of the meanings makes a lot of sense, and the other one doesn't. "The [principle of charity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_charity) or charitable interpretation requires interpreting a speaker's statements in the most rational way possible."    If there is no way to pick the best meaning, then perhaps you can provisionally imagine they have said *both* things.

Comment: This is great - thank you. You completely answered my question, and the fundamental misconception that lead to it. I would upvote but I don't have the privileges to do so yet. I will return to do so when I have them!